# Phoenix/Ecto - query for single record with a nil value

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

In my Phoenix app, I'd like to run a `get_by()` Ecto query for a single record - however, one of the fields that I want to search on should evaluate to `nil`, but Phoenix/Ecto forbids using `nil` as a comparison operator.

Here's my ideal (but failing) query:

```
target_record = Repo.get_by(Records, %{user_id: user_id, deleted_at: nil})
```

I have been able to query for `nil` fields using `is_nil(field_name)` in a query for many records, such as:

```
target_records = from(r in Records,
                        where: r.user_id == ^user_id,
                        where: is_nil(r.deleted_at))
                        |> Repo.all()
```

but the I am reluctant to use that for my current task because that will return a list... my `Records` table can have many entries with the same `user_id` but only one of those entries will ever have `deleted_at: nil`, so there's no need for me to get back a list of one item and then convert it into a map...

I mean, I can do that, but it doesn't seem very clean.

How should a `get_by` query be arranged so that a `nil` value can be included?

Comment: Why not use `Repo.one` instead of `Repo.all` if you know there will be only 1 record?

Comment: Pretty simple reason... just didn't know about it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `Repo.get` and `Repo.get_by` are great for very simple queries. However, when you need to go beyond what they can do, you'll need to drop into the `Ecto.Query` API. Queries build with this API can be used with `Repo.one`, `Repo.one!`, and `Repo.all`. Note that `Repo.one` will raise if it gets more than 1 record.

So, this should work:

```
target_records = 
  from(r in Records, where: r.user_id == ^user_id and is_nil(r.deleted_at))
  |> Repo.one()
```

and can be written like:

```
target_records = 
  Repo.one from r in Records, where: r.user_id == ^user_id and is_nil(r.deleted_at)
```

Comment: When I posted this, I was like 'alright, when's Steve gonna see this?'